# Dynamics CRM OnPrem NavigateTo

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am using Dynamics CRM onPrem version 9.0.10,

In the unified interface I try to use navigateTo function as documented in here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/navigateto

But I am getting an error in the error callback function that says that an error occured with this code -2147220715,

Here is my code :

```
var pageInput = {
            pageType: "webresource",
            webresourceName: "el_AddBenefits.html" // my html page - name taken from crm
        };
        var navigationOptions = {
            target: 2,
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            position: 1
        };
        Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(pageInput, navigationOptions).then(
            function success(result) {
                debugger;
                // Handle dialog closed
            },
            function error(result) {
                debugger;
                // Handle errors - here i am getting my -2147220715 error 
            }
        );
```

Comment: is your webresource name `el_AddBenefits.html` or is it just `el_AddBenefits`

Comment: el_AddBenefits.html is the name , but i allready tried without ".html" just to be sure and got the same error

Comment: did you managed to figure it out.

Comment: It seems that this is not working on OnPrem enviroment 9.0.10 and maybe this is only for Online enviroment , hope i'm wrong.

Comment: I believe you have to wait for release in onprem, as you aware online get updates annually twice but onprem get once in a year. Also online orgs get frequent updates almost every weekends :)

Answer (score 0):

CRM online gets frequent updates and major upgrades twice a year. Whereas on-premise version gets almost a year delayed upgrade/updates.

So please follow the release notes for on-prem updates and keep an eye for such features, as you may know like online - you may not get a chance to try early access for such stuffs in on-prem sandbox instances.